# Deleted Partitions now laptop wont start

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning

my laptop was previously dual boot windows/linux. I removed linux, and re-installed windows, and upgraded to windows 10. My partitions were still all out of whack so i used a partition tool to try and add all my unallocated space back to my fresh windows install. I think i deleted some recovery partitions somehow... the tool restarted my computer, and before boot started doing stuff at a terminal like screen for the partitions. at one point i got thee windows 10 error screen which said I will need to run a repair.

I went to create a USB install media to run the repair, but in the time I was gone my screen went black and wouldnt come back. I held the power button to shut down, and then pressed it to turn on.

Heres my issue - every other post says things about entering the bios to boot via usb and run my repair, or do some disk utilities to fix it, etc. I can't even get this far.

When i press the power button of my laptop, the light on the power button comes on but I do not hear the harddrive spinning up, and it looks like the monitor never even turns on, and im just at a pure black, silent laptop.

Anyone have any idea what to do? :(

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is deeper than missing partitions on a hard drive. Even if the hard drive is removed from the computer you should still get a splash screen of some sort. You might actually try removing the hard drive physically to see if this happens. Also, in the age of SSDs, your hard drive might not make any sound.

Comment: Since you just reinstall Windows, I suggest just cutting your loses, and installing Windows again.  In the future if you don't understand a partition operation, you should come seek help, to better understand it.